# ASP.NET MVC4 Is it possible to return two lists of complex types to a controller in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model

I have a model which contains (amongst other things) two lists of classes:

```
public class JobStructureViewModel
{ 
    public List<SimpleControl> Controls { get; set; }

    public List<JobStructureTasksModel> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

I am displaying them in a Razor view with an editor template:

```
@model ConnectManager2.Models.JobStructureViewModel

   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateJob", "JobCreator", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "datagrid" }))
    {

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Tasks)

   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Controls)
   <input style="display: none; width: 150px; height: 100%; margin: 0px; float: right; margin-right: 1.7em;" class="btn btn-default" id="createJobInput" type="submit" value="Submit Job" />
}
```

This is the signature of my POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateJob(JobStructureViewModel model)
```

My problem is that when the form is posted back to the controller one of the lists is always null. If I remove one of the lists then the other one is returned successfully, but the framework doesn't seem to be able to cope with more than one list in a single view. 
Is there a way to make this possible or will I have to try another approach?

There are the classes for 'Tasks' and 'Controls' and the views they use.

```
public class JobStructureTasksModel
{

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Contract { get; set; }

    public int TaskID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the required quantity")]
    [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be between 1 and 100")]
    public float ReqQty { get; set; }

    public string skillset { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}


@model ConnectManager2.Models.JobStructureTasksModel
<tr id ="@Model.TaskID">
<td>@Model.Code
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Code)
</td>
<td> @Model.Description
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Description)
</td> 
<td> @Model.Contract
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Contract)
</td>
<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ReqQty, new {style = "width:25%" ,onchange = "taskqtychanged()"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ReqQty)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Delete, new {taskid = @Model.TaskID,  onclick = "taskDeleted(this)" })
</td>
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TaskID)
</tr>


 public class SimpleControl
 {
    public SimpleControl()
    {
        Options = new List<string>();

    }

    public string Template { get; set; }
    public string CtrlType { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LabelText { get; set; }

    public string PageName { get; set; }

    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }

    public string InitialValue { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool CheckBoxValue { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateVal { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan? TimeVal { get; set; }

    public List<string> Options { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + "; " + Value == null ? "" : Value;
    }
 }


@model JobClassLib.TemplateRoutines.SimpleControl
<div>
<div class="row padtop" id ="@Model.Name">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label>@Model.LabelText</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @if (Model.CtrlType == "textbox")
        {
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { @class = "form-control add-job-field" })
            </td>
        }
        else if (Model.CtrlType == "multilinetextbox")
        {
            <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Value, new { @class = "form-control add-job-field" })
            </td>
         }
         else if (Model.CtrlType == "combobox" || Model.CtrlType == "outcomecombobox")
         {
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Value,
new SelectList(Model.Options, Model.Value), new { @class = "form-control    add-job-field" })
            </td>
        }
        else if (Model.CtrlType == "checkbox")
        {
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.CheckBoxValue)
            </td>
        }
        else if (Model.CtrlType == "datepicker")
        {
            DateTime dt = (Model.DateVal.HasValue) ? Model.DateVal.Value : DateTime.Now;
            string dateString = dt.ToString(Telecetera.Common.BaseFormats.DateDBFormat);
            <td>@Html.TextBox("DateVal", dateString, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control" })
            </td>

            <script>
                setInitialValue = function () {
                    $("#" + @Model.Name + " > input").val('@dateString');
                }
                setInitialValue();
            </script>

        }
        else if (Model.CtrlType == "timepicker")
        {
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TimeVal, new { ctrltype = "time" })
            </td>
        }
        else if (Model.CtrlType == "listview")
        {
            <td>
                <input class="btn btn-default min-width-btn"  type="button" onclick="jobCreationLVClicked('@Model.Name','@Model.Template','@Model.LabelText')" lvid="@Model.Name" value="@Model.GetLVCount(Model.Name, Model.Template)" />
            </td>
        }
        else if (Model.CtrlType == "customer")
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Value)
            <script>
                $('#'+ '@Model.Name').hide();
            </script>
        }
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PageName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.LabelText)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CtrlType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Template)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserID)

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can post back as many lists as your want. What is the signature of your POST method?

Comment: The code you have shown will bind fine. What are all those `onclick` and `onchange` scripts doing?

Comment: They call routines to edit some of the data in a modal dialog.

Comment: After more digging I have discovered that this problem only occurs when the controls list only has one item in it.If it has two or more items then the tasks are returned correctly to the server, but not when there is only one item for some reason!